# MongoDB unusual error perhaps?

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

today I wanted to move on from SQL Ce to MongoDB. I downloaded the driver and ran the server locally on my PC.

Here's my actual code (btw I don't even know if it's safe to cast IMongoCollection to MongoCollection):

```
using System;
using MongoDB.Driver;

namespace MongoShit
{
    class Program
    {
        class Apple
        {
            public int price, weight;
            public string color;

            public Apple()
            {
                price = 0;
                weight = 0;
                color = "ayye";
            }
        }

        static protected IMongoClient client;
        static protected IMongoDatabase database;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost");
            database = client.GetDatabase("test");

            database.CreateCollection("apples");

            var data = new Apple() { price = 100, weight = 500, color = "green" };

            MongoCollection<Apple> collection = (MongoCollection<Apple>)database.GetCollection<Apple>("apples");
            collection.Insert(data);

            var cursor = collection.FindAll();
            foreach(Apple a in cursor)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Apple, P: {0}   W: {1}   C: {2}", new object[] { a.price, a.weight, a.color }));
            }
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

But whenever I try to run the program I get the following error:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

What's going on? :S

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to cast to MongoCollection so this line should work for you

```
var collection = database.GetCollection<Apple>("apples");
```

Also, you don't need to explicitly create a collection, MongoDB will do this if one does not already exist, so this line can go

```
 database.CreateCollection("apples");
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem with Mongo 2.4's NuGet package, the dependency is missing.
It was fixed on Oct 26th, but not on NuGet yet.

You can either use 2.3, or add the dependency manually for now until the update gets pushed.